# gnucash CSV import produces "target split is currently hidden in this register"

Tags: import, cvs, gnucash

I imported a CSV file from PayPal into my PayPal account (register), and found that strangely nothing had imported ... or at least it looked like nothing imported. So I tried again, and again, but newly recorded transactions would just not show in my PayPal account.

So I checked one of my categories to see if anything was getting recorded, and found matching entries from my imported data. I clicked on **Jump to the other account** to go to the PayPal account and found this:

[image: target split is currently hidden in this register]

If I click OK is see the newly imported data into my PayPal account (unfortunately now in multiples) but can't get the transactions to keep showing if reopening that PayPal account after closing it.

What is going on? How can I get these imported transactions to show normally?

Answer (score 0):

I found later that I had this Date End Filter on; changing it to Today helped matter:

[image]